# How to create simple Js Animation in Foundation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am trying to learn how to add fade in and out animations on my Foundation 6 site. I tried learning from the docs, but it confuses me.

Can I know how I can use Foundation built-in animation to HTML elements or how do I implement external Js libraries.

Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Please be more descriptive. Where in the site ? Do you want the animation to show on hover ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Add some code snippet

Comment: I don't have any code snippet because I don't know how to do it. For example, I want a fade to the section when I click a link on the nav bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple Fade effect used from an external JS file. This is compatible with both Foundation 6 & Bootstrap 4

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.css" />

<div class="row">
    <center>
      <div class="large-12 column" style="background-color:#FF9999;">
          <h1 class="hello">Hello,</h1>
           <br>
             <p class="hello">My young friend</p>
      </div>
     </center> 
  </div>

<div class="row">
    <center>
      <div class="large-12 column" style="background-color:#c45c61;">
          <h1 class="hello">Welcome,</h1>
           <br>
             <p class="hello">to your jedi training</p>
      </div>
     </center> 
  </div>


<div class="row">
    <center>
      <div class="large-12 column" style="background-color:#f2c698;">
          <h1 class="hello">Hello,</h1>
           <br>
             <p class="hello">My young friend</p>
      </div>
     </center> 
  </div>

<!-- JS Plugins -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
/**** Making the class invisible until called upon ****/
.hello {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 25px 0 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
 }
/**** Making the class invisible until called upon ****/




/**** calling the functionality to the class (this is called by the JS) ****/
.FadeIn {
    -webkit-animation: slideIn 0.8s ease 0.3s forwards;
    animation: slideIn 0.8s ease 0.3s forwards;
}
/**** calling the functionality to the class (this is called by the JS) ****/





/**** BEFORE & AFTER for the animation i.e. 0% to 100% - make the change, two because of browser compatability  ****/


@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}


@keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/**** BEFORE & AFTER for the animation i.e. 0% to 100% - make the change, two because of browser compatibility  ****/
```

JS:

```
var $fade =  $(".hello"); //Calling the class in HTML

$(window).scroll(function () { //Using the scroll global variable
    $fade.each(function () {

        fadeMiddle = $(this).offset().top + (0.4 *$(this).height());
        windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if (fadeMiddle < windowBottom) {
          $(this).addClass("FadeIn");
        }
    });
});

/* On Load: Trigger Scroll Once*/
$(window).scroll();
```

This can be seen in action here: https://codepen.io/billyfarroll/pen/yKRNBM